# Popup message by column for DT::datatable that is part of an html markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Hi I've seen several similar question as to have pop for each column of a DT::datatable however all of them are for shiny and relies on a JS call.  However is there a way to do this when its part of an html markdown? for example,

```
DT::datatable ( head ( iris ) )
```

is it possible, two have sepal.width and patel.length have a yellow pop up displaying test1 and test2, respectively?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this but these are basic tooltips:

```
library(DT)

headerCallback <- c(
  "function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
  "  var tooltips = ['tooltip1','tooltip2','tooltip3','tooltip4','tooltip5'];",
  "  for(var i=0; i<5; i++){",
  "    $('th:eq('+i+')',thead).attr('title', tooltips[i]);",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

datatable(iris, rownames = FALSE, 
          options = list(
            headerCallback = JS(headerCallback)
          )
)
```